# FTP Client/Server Login Authentication

Tags: java, sockets, server, ftp, client

I have a question about creating an FTP client in Java.

I created somewhat of an FTP client that should work, but when I run it on the terminal it stops, waits a while, and then returns an error message. The client has to connect to a server IP address which needs a username and password to authenticate and login. However, I cannot get the login to work.

I do not have to create the FTP server, there is already a server located in our institution that I have to connect to.

This is the code I have so far for the FTP client:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class FTPC
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String option;
        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        Socket s=new Socket("10.246.251.39",Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("1.SEND");
        System.out.println("2.RECEIVE");
        FTPC ftp=new FTPC();

        while(true)
        {
            option=in.readLine();
            if(option.equals("1")){
                System.out.println("SEND Command Received..");
                ftp.sendfile(s);
            }
            else if(option.equals("2")){
                System.out.println("RECEIVE Command Received..");
                ftp.receivefile(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendfile(Socket s) throws Exception
    {
        Socket ssock=s;

        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);

        DataInputStream cin=new DataInputStream(ssock.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream cout=new DataOutputStream(ssock.getOutputStream());

        cout.writeUTF("RECEIVE");

        String filename=in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Reading File "+filename);
        cout.writeUTF(filename);
        File f=new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(f);
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch=fin.read();
            cout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ch));
        }while(ch!=-1);
        fin.close();
        System.out.println("File Sent");
    }

    public void receivefile(Socket s) throws Exception
    {
        Socket ssock=s;
        DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        DataInputStream cin=new DataInputStream(ssock.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream cout=new DataOutputStream(ssock.getOutputStream());

        cout.writeUTF("SEND");

        String filename=in.readLine();
        cout.writeUTF(filename);
        System.out.println("Receiving File "+filename);
        File f=new File(filename);
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(f);
        int ch;
        do
        {
            ch=Integer.parseInt(cin.readUTF());
            if(ch!=-1) fout.write(ch);
        }while(ch!=-1);
        System.out.println("Received File...");
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `readLine` method of `DataInputStream` is deprecated and should be replaced with the `BufferedReader`'s `readLine` method.

Comment: Why is `receivefile` writing to a `FileOutputStream` while `sendfile` is reading from a `FileInputStream`? Is there something that I've missed?

Comment: Hey Leftist, its because when you are receiving a file you are getting the file from the server, and when you are sending a file you are inputting the file and sending it to the server

Comment: This code is not even remotely close to being a correct FTP client.  Read [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) for the FTP protocol specification.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues here:

1. The login conversation is missing entirely (commands `USER` & `PASS`).
2. You are establishing a single socket and using it for both commands and data, but FTP uses a control connection (usually on port 21) for commands and a data connection (usually on port 20) for data transfers.
3. Neither `SEND` nor `RECEIVE` are FTP commands. Instead, use `STOR` & `RETR`.  (See the [List of FTP commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands).)
4. Your client lacks the `CWD` and `LIST` commands. These are essential.